# Interpret as fixed string/literal and not regex using sed

Tags: unix, sed

For `grep` there's a fixed string option, `-F` (`fgrep`) to turn off regex interpretation of the search string.
Is there a similar facility for `sed`?  I couldn't find anything in the man. A recommendation of another gnu/linux tool would also be fine.

I'm using `sed` for the find and replace functionality: `sed -i "s/abc/def/g"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape a string for sed search pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-sed-search-pattern)

Comment: It is amazing no one answered your actual question of treating the string like a string instead of a regex. I would give my left arm for that answer right now. I really wish folks answering the question would read the question and answer the question that was asked...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You should be using `replace` instead of `sed`.

From the man page:

```
   The replace utility program changes strings in place in files or on the
   standard input.

   Invoke replace in one of the following ways:

       shell> replace from to [from to] ... -- file_name [file_name] ...
       shell> replace from to [from to] ... < file_name

   from represents a string to look for and to represents its replacement.
   There can be one or more pairs of strings.
```

Comment: hmmm, don't have 'replace' installed - it looks to be a MySQL related tool?  I have MySql installed; is there a separate install for replace?

Comment: It doesn't come in a separate package, sorry. You could try to find it in the mysql source tree and build it yourself, but that is a lot of hassle. So you have mysql, but not `/usr/bin/replace`? You could try and reinstall the mysql package (`mysql-server`).

Comment: not in /usr/bin and can't reinstall! I'll accept your answer assuming that it works :)

Comment: Due to the absence of `/usr/bin/replace` on most systems, this does not appear as a universal answer to me.

Comment: another major flaw with `replace` is that it doesn't do backups when doing inplace edits.

Comment: I installed MariaDB, copied `/usr/bin/replace` to my `~/.local/bin` (in `$PATH`) and then uninstalled it.
Funny how this answer [get a lot of votes on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1170402/500826).

Comment: maybe `$someone` should package [mysql/extra/replace.c](http://www.iskm.org/mysql56/replace_8c_source.html) ...

Answer (score 11):

Do you have to use `sed`?  If you're writing a bash script, you can do

```sh
#!/bin/bash

pattern='abc'
replace='def'
file=/path/to/file
tmpfile="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/$( basename "$file" ).$$"

while read -r line
do
  echo "${line//$pattern/$replace}"
done < "$file" > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" "$file"
```

With an older Bourne shell (such as ksh88 or POSIX sh), you may not have that cool `${var/pattern/replace}` structure, but you do have `${var#pattern}` and `${var%pattern}`, which can be used to split the string up and then reassemble it.  If you need to do that, you're in for a lot more code - but it's really not too bad.

If you're not in a shell script already, you could pretty easily make the pattern, replace, and filename parameters and just call this. :)

PS: The `${TMPDIR:-/tmp}` structure uses `$TMPDIR` if that's set in your environment, or uses /tmp if the variable isn't set.  I like to stick the PID of the current process on the end of the filename in the hopes that it'll be slightly more unique.  You should probably use `mktemp` or similar in the "real world", but this is ok for a quick example, and the `mktemp` binary isn't always available.

Comment: This is a slow solution. echo is called for every line of the file which could fork thousands of echo processes if you are using a large file or multiple files.

Comment: echo is typically implemented as a shell builtin, which should fork 0 processes on a modern shell like bash.

Comment: You can see the builtins at work by using "strace -e trace=process ./shellscript".  Write the above script, and see how many fork calls there are.  Using a current Bash on a current Ubuntu, there are 2 fork (actually clone(), which is faster than fork()) calls.  One for the subshell where basename is executed, and one for the mv.  If you rewrote this using "/bin/echo", on the other hand, then there is actually a new fork for every line.  And you could see it taking a *lot* longer to run. :)

Comment: I guess this will only work for lines containing "save" characters. I tried to replace all lines that contain exactly one star "*" and it failed.

Comment: You need to escape shell metachars in $replace, probably like `replace='*'`. If you don't escape, the asterisk expands to all the files in the path where you run the script. But if you want exactly one *, you'd also need to use shell regexps. Which are a somewhat more advanced topic.

Comment: Also, to avoid read and echo replacing things like `\n` and `-e` you probably want to do something like `while read -r line;do printf "%s\n" "${line/$pattern/$replace}";done`

Comment: The printf commands is a builtin less often than echo, depending on the shell, so one needs to be careful of that. In real life, I'd personally use ksh and `print --` instead of echo. But good point about `read -r`. I'm editing the answer since that's in the POSIX standard.

Comment: I'll just leave this here....  [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Comment: There are inaccuracies in that explanation that most of the reasons are built upon ("variable scope is hard" and performance is bad if you use a crappy shell), and the rest is just opinion about "readability" - like putting the same code inside a loop suddenly makes it completely illegible. :)

Answer (score 6):

Option 1) Escape regexp characters.  E.g. `sed 's/\$0\.0/0/g'` will replace all occurrences of $0.0 with 0.

Option 2) Use `perl -p -e` in conjunction with quotemeta.  E.g. `perl -p -e 's/\\./,/gi'` will replace all occurrences of `.` with `,`.

You can use option 2 in scripts like this:

```bash
SEARCH="C++"
REPLACE="C#"
cat $FILELIST | perl -p -e "s/\\Q$SEARCH\\E/$REPLACE/g" > $NEWLIST
```

Comment: Has perl got an equivalent of sed's -i?  I'm using sed as follows: find -name "*myfiles*" |xargs sed -i "s/abc/def/g"

Comment: I'm seeing your perl example get interpreted as a regex!

Comment: $ echo "a.b.c" | perl -p -e 's/./,/g' gives me ",,,,," and not "a,b,c"

Comment: @EoghanM: That's because you need to escape `.`, otherwise it will match any character.

Comment: @EogchanM -- I missed the leading \Q and trailing \E.  So the first example should be perl -p e 's/\Q.\E/,/gi'.  I added i as well to make it case insensitive.

Comment: On re-editing the post, I just found that I did indeed escape the . the first time with a '\', but it doesn't show up in the finally formatted message. Oh well.  Hope I didn't confuse more than I helped! :-)

Comment: @Kim, you can escape inline text by putting backticks around it (the same way as you escape block text by indenting it by 4 chars).

Comment: Perl does have a -i argument which works just like the sed -i arg.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not opposed to Ruby or long lines, you could use this:

```bash
alias replace='ruby -e "File.write(ARGV[0], File.read(ARGV[0]).gsub(ARGV[1]) { ARGV[2] })"'

replace test3.txt abc def
```

This loads the whole file into memory, performs the replacements and saves it back to disk. Should probably not be used for massive files.

Comment: gsub interpolates the back-references in the replacement string. You won't be able to replace things like '\2' with '\1'

Comment: @Sorin True, fixed :)

Answer (score 4):

If you *don't* want to escape your string, you can reach your goal in 2 steps:

1. `fgrep` the line (getting the line number) you want to replace, and
2. afterwards use `sed` for replacing this line.

E.g.

```sh
#/bin/sh
PATTERN='foo*[)*abc'    # we need it literal
LINENUMBER="$( fgrep -n "$PATTERN" "$FILE" | cut -d':' -f1 )"

NEWSTRING='my new string'
sed -i "${LINENUMBER}s/.*/$NEWSTRING/" "$FILE"
```

Comment: Efficient, concise, and inplace!

Comment: great idea. And we can also kick out `cut` and use standard 'grep': `line_num=$(grep -Fn "$PATTERN" "$FILE"); line_num=${line_num%%:*}` and it's still POSIX

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two lines of bash code if you're OK with reading the whole file into memory.  This is quite flexible -- the pattern and replacement can contain newlines to match across lines if needed.  It also preserves any trailing newline or lack thereof, which a simple loop with `read` does not.

```bash
mapfile -d '' < file
printf '%s' "${MAPFILE//"$pat"/"$rep"}" > file
```

For completeness, if the file can contain null bytes (`\0`), we need to extend the above, and it becomes

```bash
mapfile -d '' < <(cat file; printf '\0')
last=${MAPFILE[-1]}; unset "MAPFILE[-1]"
printf '%s\0' "${MAPFILE[@]//"$pat"/"$rep"}" > file
printf '%s' "${last//"$pat"/"$rep"}" >> file
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
perl -i.orig -pse  'while (($i = index($_,$s)) >= 0) { substr($_,$i,length($s), $r)}'--\ 
     -s='$_REQUEST['\'old\'']' -r='$_REQUEST['\'new\'']' sample.txt
```

- `-i.orig` in-place modification with backup.
- `-p` print lines from the input file by default
- `-s` enable rudimentary parsing of command line arguments
- `-e` run this script
- `index($_,$s)` search for the `$s` string
- `substr($_,$i,length($s), $r)` replace the string
- `while (($i = index($_,$s)) >= 0)` repeat until
- `--` end of perl parameters
- `-s='$_REQUEST['\'old\'']'`, `-r='$_REQUEST['\'new\'']'` - set `$s`,`$r`

You still need to "escape" `'` chars but the rest should be straight forward.

Note: this started as an answer to [How to pass special character string to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60567208/how-to-pass-special-character-string-to-sed) hence the `$_REQUEST['old']` strings, however this question is a bit more appropriately formulated.