# How to create .ini file using bash using template

Tags: bash, templates, properties, ini

I am new to shell scripting. And trying to create a .ini file with following details.
End result of .ini file:

```
[dev]
JDBC_URL = jdbc:h2:mem:mem_test;MODE=Oracle
JDBC_USERNAME =
JDBC_PASSWORD =

SERVICE_ENDPOINT = http://localhost:8080/Central/api/AppService

[qa]
JDBC_URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@qa-oracle:1521:qa
JDBC_USERNAME = qauser
JDBC_PASSWORD = qapass

SERVICE_ENDPOINT = http://qa-services/Central/api/AppService

[prod]
JDBC_URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@prod-oracle:1521:prod
JDBC_USERNAME = scott
JDBC_PASSWORD = tiger

SERVICE_ENDPOINT = http://prod-services/Central/api/AppService
```

How to start with creating .ini file using bash. You can also suggest with some example, if their is some other way in bash using template to do same.

Comment: This might help: [Create new file from templates with bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6214743/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus, i already had a look on this, but it doesn't solve my purpose as i am looking for creating multi section file with common fields in each seaction. And by section i mean dev, qa, prod.

Comment: @BleedCode, why don't you crate a property file eg--> `JDBC_URL`, `JDBC_USERNAME`,`JDBC_pass` and `URL` etc and then provide values there, you could easily use `while` or `awk` to read that file and could create these kind of files then, let me know on same if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried creating a property file using template, but with that option also i am not able to create sections. @RavinderSingh13 .If you have any example on same you can share that would be a great help.

Comment: @BleedCode, I tried in a `while` script please check and let me know, though I am not sure about your requirement fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you create following property Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
dev,bla-bla-bla,user_singh,singh,http://chumma.com
qa,bla-bla-bla,user_singh1,http://chumma1.com
```

It's value are in format of `environment,JDBC_URL,user,pass,service_point`
Then following may help you on same.

```
while IFS=, read environment jdbc_url user pass service
do
   echo -e "[" $environment "]\nJDBC_URL = $jdbc_url\nJDBC_USERNAME = $user\nJDBC_PASSWORD = $pass\nSERVICE_ENDPOINT = $service"
done < "Input_file"
```

Comment: But echo won't prints the value in properties file. It prints on console.

Comment: @BleedCode, you mean you need to create a single output file or multiple output files?

Comment: One template file using which one properties file should be created with above content which i provided in example.

Comment: @BleedCode, sorry didn't get it please be more clear on it.

Comment: @BleedCode: Replace `"Input_file"` with `"Input_file" > "properties.ini"` to redirect stdout to a file.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 in bash we have a template for creating properties file. For more understanding go through this: Create new file from templates with bash script". So my question is same but i need a template with multiple sections.