# How to use an environment variable in sed when finding strings between two patterns?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to find a way to find all string between two patterns. This is easy:

```
    cat file | sed -n "/pattern_start/,/pattern_end/p"
```

However, in this case I want to use a variable inside the sed script, which also is fine:

```
    cat file | sed -n "/$var1/,/pattern_end/p"
```

However, if the variable contains special escape characters such as, '/' this does not work. Then I read that one could replace the escape character to anything, such as # or |

For example, lets say:

```
    var1=/some/funny/path
    cat file | sed -n "#$var1#,#pattern_end#p"
```

But this does not work for me. What am I doing wrong? I have tried to find the answer on Google etc but without success and I cant really find any other question here on Stackoverflow which deals with this exact problem.

Comment: don't use `cat` command for this.

Comment: What's the value for `var1` variable? Please show your file for us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape a previously unknown string in regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328995/how-to-escape-a-previously-unknown-string-in-regular-expression)

Comment: I made an edit to the question so it will be more clear what var1 looks like.

Comment: @hek2mgl The solution in that answer has limitations.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133286/sed-or-similar-dont-interpret-as-regex-interpret-as-fixed-string-literal or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern

Comment: I do not want to replace something. That is what all examples shows, but not how to deal with this problem I explained.

Comment: @ceving The post you linked is about replacement. This one is not about replacement.

Comment: @hek2mgl it does not matter if you use the regular expression in a replacement or a search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the delimiter, you need to escape the first one, i.e. something like, `\!FIND!`. Also, it is best to use single quotes, leave them when needed and use double quotes for variable interpolation. Then your command looks like this:

```
sed -n '\!'"$var1"'!,\!'"$var2"'!p' inpu
```

Comment: Good advice, but what if the contents of the variable contain *that* delimiter?

Comment: Then you go and find a better delimiter.

Comment: Since you don't know the contents of the variable beforehand, there's no such thing as a "better" delimiter. Better to pick a delimiter, then protect that character in the input.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
sed -n "/$(sed 's#/#\\/#g' <<< "$var1")/,/end/p" file
```

You'll have to protect the contents of your variable from whatever delimiters you choose.

---

To address hek2mgl's concern, we could escape all potentially troublesome characters:

```
re_escape() {
    sed 's#[^[:alnum:]_]#\\&#g' <<< "$*"
}
sed -n "/$(re_escape "$var1")/,/end/p" file
```

Comment: (this is what I would had suggested too but) what if `$var1` contains something like `\(` or other characters which may be interpreted by sed , except of the delimiter? (off-topic) In PHP there is a function called `preg_quote()` which can be used for this. Would be nice to have something like this. I guess a bash function can help (if well prepared)

Comment: I predict the same comment could be made for every solution to this question.

Comment: And for further readers, perl has the `quotemeta` function for this purpose; ruby has `Regexp.escape`; python, `re.escape` -- I think all of these merely escape all non-word characters.

Comment: @hek2mgl, here's a bash function for you.

Comment: Looks good! `[^[:alnum]_]` should work in most or even all(?) cases. Much simpler than what I had in mind. Btw, "my" sed (GNU-sed-Version 4.2.1
) interpretes `_` as `alnum`. Is this not safe for other versions of sed?

Comment: Are you sure? I have the same version and this outputs nothing: `echo "---_---" | sed -n '/[[:alnum:]]/p'`