# How to pass special character string to sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Am trying to pass special character string to sed command but no success i tried backslash but no success

```
sed -i 's/old/new/g' {} +   # working 

sed -i 's/$_REQUEST['old']/$_REQUEST['new']/g' {} +   # not working 
sed -i 's/$_REQUEST[\'old\']/$_REQUEST[\'new\']/g' {} +   # not working 
sed -i "s/$_REQUEST['old']/$_REQUEST['new']/g" {} +  # NIGHTMARE ! not working
```

Comment: @anubhava ya i have tried that too earlier it not worked ,  forgot to add in question

Comment: There's no parameter passing going on here. You are constructing a `sed` script that will have the value hard-coded into it.

Comment: since `$_REQUEST` is PHP specific, I'm going to guess you are constructing this from a PHP script, in which case simply dumping user input into a shell script like you are attempting to do would expose you to a world of trouble. Imagine if $_REQUEST['old'] contains `/g" {} + -delete`

Comment: @Sorin no am executing command from ssh terminal

Comment: @Sorin ya its dangerous :) above you can see NIGHTMARE ! not working  , it replaced everything in file , good that i had back of it

Comment: @user889030 that's why the gods who created sed -i gave you the option to make a backup  `sed -i.orig ..`

Comment: @Sorin no it not helped , here i tested : https://repl.it/repls/AlarmedDesertedExam

Comment: @user889030, it helped, but you have additional stuff to escape see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script

Comment: @tripleee - the duplicate question is wrong, this is the more appropriate duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133286/interpret-as-fixed-string-literal-and-not-regex-using-sed/60569576#60569576  (sorry, got caught in writing the answer and didn't change the duplicate). @user889030 - see also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60569576/939457 - it would eliminate the need for escaping any chars (except `'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to include single quotes inside a single quoted string, not even by escaping them.

And with double quotes, the shell will expand the `$_REQUEST` variable (probably substituting the empty string).

Try this:

```sh
sed -i 's/\$_REQUEST\['\'old\''\]/$_REQUEST['\'new\'']/g' {} + 
# ...................^^...^^..............^^...^^
```

Those are the literal single quotes placed *outside* the single quoted string chunks.

Or, escape the dollars inside double quotes:

```sh
sed -i "s/\\\$_REQUEST\\['old'\\]/\$_REQUEST['new']/g" {} +
# ,.......^.................^.
```

Edited to include the escapes required for the regex-special characters in the left-hand side

Comment: no success i tried it , can you check : https://repl.it/repls/AlarmedDesertedExam

Comment: you need to escape also `[` and `]` - see https://ideone.com/26noqF

Comment: @sorin: d'oh! thanks.

Comment: @Sorin why it not working here in terminal i copy and paste you command : https://repl.it/repls/AlarmedDesertedExam

Comment: @glennjackman thanks man  escaping the dollars inside double quotes worked

Comment: You don't need `\\\$` in the search `\$` would suffice, `$` is treated as a special char only at the end of the regular expression (or sub-expression) - for anyone wondering why  https://ideone.com/26noqF works without `\\\$` ;)